# MVC 5 Filtered Lists with dynamic labels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list

I am relatively new to MVC and I'm looking to add a feature to my web application but I am in need of some advice to point me in the right direction.

I am looking to add filtered lists (Cascarding dropdown lists) that have a label associated with that particular list for example:

How are you Feeling today? <--- label with
Dropdown list:
Happy,
Sad

*User selects Happy*

Why are you happy? <-- label generates based on users feedback. This also has a dropdown list with options.

Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript. Either by creating new dropdown lists on the fly or by revealing previously hidden ones.

Comment: This is something that's pretty trivial with Javascript, so my advice would be to take a few hours and go through the W3Schools tutorials. After that, you'll just need to do some googling on doing X when a dropdown changes. My advice would be to create some "empty" dropdowns that are hidden and then use the javascript to add the actual optoins to them.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but would the above suggestion of JavaScript work within the View or would I need to POST back to the controller still?

Comment: No, it's cool. With Javascript it'd all be client-side, no postbacks required.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate all the advice, I'll look into Javascipt and how to use it in the View to make Labels and Dropdown Lists become visible upon feedback.

Comment: You won't regret it! If you're going to do any kind of real web design, you gotta have Javascript!